# Flutter Bloc - How to handle real-time input changes in TextField and update Bloc state?

Tags: android, mobile, bloc

I'm working on a Flutter application where I have a TextField for entering age, and I'm using the Bloc pattern to manage state. The issue I'm facing is that every time I enter a digit, it overwrites the previous one, and I can't input more than one digit at a time. I've noticed that each time I update the state, the age widget rebuilds, and the ageController loses its previous data. If I initialize the state data in the controller after it rebuilds, the cursor placement problem appears. Then, I can't remove digits from the middle; each time, it moves to the end.

**Widget preview: **

[image: Age widget]

**Here's a snippet of my code:**

```
Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 15),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              ),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  //context.read<AgeCalBloc>().add(WeightUnitChangeEvent());
                },
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "YEAR",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
          ),
          height: 200,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Age",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondaryContainer,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              TextField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                controller: ageController,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                    context
                        .read<AgeCalBloc>()
                        .add(UpdateAgeTextFielsEvent(value));
                  });
                },
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText:
                      "${state.age  ?? "22")}",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 60,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Theme.of(context)
                        .colorScheme
                        .onBackground
                        .withOpacity(0.5),
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  SecBtn(
                    onpress: () {
                      //Plus
                      if (state.age == null || state.age.toString().isEmpty) {
                        ageController.text = "22";
                      } else {
                        ageController.text = state.age.toString();
                      }
                      int age = int.parse(ageController.text);
                      age++;
                      ageController.text = age.toString();
                      context
                          .read<AgeCalBloc>()
                          .add(UpdateAgeTextFielsEvent(ageController.text));
                    },
                    icon: Icons.add,
                  ),
                  SecBtn(
                    onpress: () {
                      //Minus
                      if (state.age == null || state.age.toString().isEmpty) {
                        ageController.text = "22";
                      } else {
                        ageController.text = state.age.toString();
                      }
                      int age = int.parse(ageController.text);
                      age--;
                      ageController.text = age.toString();
                      context
                          .read<AgeCalBloc>()
                          .add(UpdateAgeTextFielsEvent(ageController.text));
                    },
                    icon: Icons.minimize,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

I've added a delay of one second to allow for inputting the full age, but this is not the solution I'm looking for. I want to handle real-time input changes and update the Bloc state accordingly.

Additionally, I'd like to achieve the following:

1. Allow users to input more than one digit at a time without overwriting or delays.
2. User can also use Plus (+), and Minus (-) button to increase and decrease the count Thay already inputted. if there is no data in controller or state it will start from an age like 22!
3. Display a hint when there is no input data, and the hint should disappear once the user starts inputting.
4. Any suggestions on how I can achieve these requirements in a clean and efficient way would be greatly appreciated.

**> Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

ans to this question given in the bloc offical repo login example!!
https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_login/lib/login/view/login_form.dart

```
class _UsernameInput extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous.username != current.username,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return TextField(
          key: const Key('loginForm_usernameInput_textField'),
          onChanged: (username) =>
              context.read<LoginBloc>().add(LoginUsernameChanged(username)),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'username',
            errorText:
                state.username.displayError != null ? 'invalid username' : null,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In this way I can input number as I expected but my plus and minus button did update the state, but it is not updating in the textfield. so, I moved to the stateful widget!